# Boundary and completion of the metric space $c_{00}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complete-spaces

Identify the boundary $\partial c_{00}$ in $\ell^p$, for each $p\in[1,\infty]$. Also, for each $p\in[1,\infty]$, identify the completion of the metric space $(c_{00},d_p)$.

Note that $c_0$ is the set of all real sequences that converge to $0$, and note that $c_{00}:= \left\{x=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in c_0\,:\,\text{ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0$ for all $n\geq N$}\right\}$

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd recommend starting with the cases $p=1$ and $p=\infty$. Once you've done these two cases, you should see what to do for the remaining $p$.

Comment: Hint:  $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^p$ if $p<\infty$ and in $c_0$ if $p=\infty.$

Comment: @Matematleta With regard to the question of completion, there is a theorem which states that every metric space (M,d) has a completion (M*,d*) such that M is dense in M*. Is this result relevant? So if I know that $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^p$, do we know that the completion of $(c_{00}, d_p)$ is $(\ell^p, d_p)$ when $p<\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

If $p<\infty$, then $\overline{c_{00}}=\ell^p$ and $\mathring{c_{00}}=\emptyset$. Therefore, $\partial c_{00}=\ell^p$ and the completion of $(c_{00},d_p)$ can be identified with $(\ell^p,d_p)$.

In $(\ell^\infty,d_\infty)$, it is still true that $\mathring{c_{00}}=\emptyset$, but now $\overline{c_{00}}=c_0$. So, $\partial c_{00}=c_0$ and the completion of $(c_{00},d_\infty)$  can be identified with $(c_0,d_\infty)$.